# The groupoid of algebraic expressions and proofs

Tags: reference-request, lo.logic, universal-algebra, groupoids, homotopy-type-theory

Fix a set of variables $V$, and suppose we're given a presentation of a monosorted algebraic theory, with variable symbols taken from $V$. For the sake of example, suppose the presentation consists of a sort symbol $U$, a function symbol $+ : U \times U \rightarrow U,$ as well as an "explicitly named identity," expressing the commutativity of addition. $$\mathsf{CoA}(x,y) : x+y = y+x$$

We think of our identities as being morphisms, whose domain and codomain are well-formed algebraic expressions. Then there is a corresponding groupoid, whose objects are the well-formed algebraic expressions, and whose arrows are proofs of equality between two expressions.

> **Question.** What is this construction called, how can we rigorously define it, and where can I read about it?

Let me be a little more explicit about what the groupoid looks like in the aforementioned example.

- Objects are well-formed algebraic expressions such as $x+y$ and $a+(b+c)$. The variable symbols have to be taken from $V$, of course; I'm assuming that $\{x,y,a,b,c\} \subseteq V$.
- Morphisms are proofs that one expression equals another. So for example, we have a morphism $$\mathsf{CoA}(x,y) : x+y = y+x$$ expressing that $x+y$ equals $y+x$; and another morphism $$a+\mathsf{CoA}(x,y) : a+(x+y) = a+(y+x)$$ expressing that $a+(x+y)$ equals $a+(y+x)$; and another morphism $$\mathsf{CoA}(x+y,a) : (x+y)+a = a+(x+y).$$ Furthermore, we can compose these to get a proof $$(\mathsf{CoA}(x+y,a)) \circ (a+\mathsf{CoA}(x,y)) : (x+y)+a = a+(y+x)$$ of the fact that $(x+y)+a=a+(y+x)$.

  Note that we can also take inverses; this allows us to get a proof that $\sigma = \tau$ from a proof that $\tau = \sigma$.

Comment: Relatively free algebra with labelling of the term algebra by congruences.  I don't recall seeing a categorification of the process as you have it here, but what you have above is not far removed from constructing the free algebra of a variety from a term algebra.

Comment: @TheMaskedAvenger, do you mean *absolutely* free algebra?

Comment: Look up higher inductive types in homotopy type theory.

Comment: There are those who might call a term algebra an absolutely free algebra.  I call it a term algebra, the free countably generated algebra in the variety of all structures of a given similarity type.

Comment: @ZhenLin: The identity types lead to an $\infty$-groupoid structure. To get a plain groupoid, one needs to truncate...

Comment: Category Theory may seem complicated and arbitrary to outsiders, but in fact it has a *tiny* number of fundamental ideas and constructions, each of which is extremely versatile and powerful and may take one decades to appreciate fully.  When you have found some construction, you will enhance your understanding by trying to identify how it is an instance or sometimes a variation on one of these fundamental constructions.  If you try to make out that it is completely different then you will add to your own and others' confusion, not your understanding.

Comment: @PaulTaylor, you misunderstand me. I would very much like to be able to view this as a special case of a more fundamental construction, perhaps the left-adjoint to some $2$-functor or some such. Nonetheless, the point remains that this groupoid-like-object is *not* a Lawvere theory in the usual sense of the word, and it cannot be recovered from the Lawvere theory. The act of passing from the presentation to the Lawvere theory throws away too much information, and we can't recover the groupoid of interest.

Comment: @PaulTaylor, now if you can see a way of describe the construction of interest by abstracting the concept "Lawvere theory" and considering "Lawvere theory objects in a $2$-category $\mathbf{C}$ with sufficient structure", and then choosing $\mathbf{C}$ carefully to explain the construction of interest, well this would be very interesting. I cannot currently see how to do this, however, and your answer offers absolutely no hints or suggestions in this direction.

Comment: It's too bad I can't upvote a dozen of times...I've been dreaming of such ideas for so long! But maybe a geometrical point of view of your groupoid would be useful too, especially if people like Maryam Mirzakhani or Misha Gromov got involved in expanding this sketch of theory. Maybe we could then use the concept of geodesics to formalize the pretty vague notion of "natural" or "direct" proof. Anyway, this question already made my day so thanks a lot for asking it!

Comment: How do you get composition to be associative?

Comment: @AndrejBauer, well the path category of a quiver is associative precisely because the domain of the forgetful functor $\mathbf{Cat} \rightarrow \mathbf{Quiv}$ is $\mathbf{Cat}$. It should be the same thing here; by choosing an appropriate forgetful functor, with the correct domain, its left adjoint should build an associative structure "automatically".

Comment: If you specify precisely how composition works (presumably an application of transitivity of equality) then there will be two ways of applyying transitivity for $a = b = c = d$, leading to the MacLane pentagon. Since you did not equate any proofs, you will not get associativity.

Comment: By the way, maybe your idea could shed a new light on a question of mine, namely http://mathoverflow.net/questions/154373/differential-galois-number-theory

Comment: @SylvainJULIEN, that's an intense look question fella. What, in particular, do you think the connection might be? By the way, your previous comment made *my* day. :)

Comment: Sorry for answering that late. To me, the concept of geodesics as mentioned in my previous comment is the connection, if you consider passing from a differential field to an extension thereof as a path in the space of differential field extensions. You can ever consider the case of classical Galois theory, considering the two $3$-tuples $A:=(\mathbb{Q},\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2}),\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2},\sqrt{3})$ and $A'$ obtained from $A$ by the permutation $(23)$ as paths from $\mathbb{Q}$ to $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2},\sqrt{3})$. The primitive element theorem then means..

Comment: ...that $A_{0}:=(\mathbb{Q},\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2}+\sqrt{3}))$ is a geodesics.

Comment: This is the $\infty$-groupoid of computational paths (for your specific deductive system with reductions given accordingly).

Answer (score 6):

That kind of algebraic manipulation and composition of proofs has strong affinities and resemblence to [Justification Logic](http://plato.stanford.edu/entries/logic-justification/), where for example one write $s:A$ to mean that $s$ is a justification (or "proof") of $A$, and then there is a composition process by which from $s:A$ and $t:A\to B$,  you may deduce $s\cdot t:B$, where $s\cdot t$ is the compositional process for implementing modus ponens. One then has other such operations, such as:

- from $s:A$ and $t:B$, deduce $(s+t):A$ and $(s+t):B$.
- from $s:A$ you may deduce $!s:s:A$.

So $s+t$ is the justification of either $A$ or $B$, and $!s$ is the proof that $s$ proves $A$. Justification logic also provides a concept of proof constant that is similar to your use of CoA(x,y).

In this way, justification logic is the logic of reasoning with explicit justifications. The idea was first suggested by Gödel, but carried further by Sergei Artemov.

(Although I find a strong resemblence between your proposal and justification logic, I am not aware of any treatment of justification logic that uses the kind of category-theoretic language you suggest.)

I just attended yesterday a [seminar talk by Mel Fitting](http://nylogic.org/talks/justification-logics) on this topic, and he mentioned that he had a number of programs available on his web page for implementing explicit manipulation of this justification algebra. (Mel Fitting was the winner of the [Herbrand prize](http://www.cadeinc.org/HerbrandAward.html) a few years ago for automated theorem proving.)

Comment: Interesting. There's definitely a strong connection there.

Comment: @goblin, that seems rather close in spirit to type theory ncatlab.org/nlab/show/type theory . In its flavors as homotopy type theory http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/homotopy+type+theory this is precisely about groupoids whose morphisms are proofs of equivalences... and higher groupoids whose higher morphisms are proofs of equivalences of proofs of equivalences, and so on.

Answer (score 6):

The construction you describe seems more like the *the category of reductions* generated by the *abstract rewrite system* given by an algebraic theory.

I suggest you take a look to section 8.2("Rewrite systems revisited") of  [*Term Rewriting System*](https://books.google.it/books/about/Term_Rewriting_Systems.html?id=oe3QKzhFEBAC&redir_esc=y) where these concepts are defined.

Here a short summary of basic the idea: you can consider a rewrite system as a graph whose vertex are terms of the signature and arrows are step of reduction.
From this data enclosing by some operations you get what in the reference is called an abstract rewrite system with compositions, whose objects are terms for the signature and whose morphisms are proof of reductions. Quotienting this structure for axioms of category you get the category of reductions.

Hope this helps.

Comment: That link is now broken, by the way. Perhaps worth relinking, or at least giving the name of the book in more detail so it can be searched by interested readers?

Comment: @goblin done that. Thanks for pointing out the problem.

Answer (score 4):

I don't have any direct reference for the notion that you are describing, however the notions of $E_n$-algebras and (topological) operads are very close. Firstly, you should note that you need equalities of higher orders, i.e. not only a proof that $a+(b+c) = (a+b)+c$, but also higher coherence laws between such proofs, like the MacLane pentagon. Let me use the language of type theory. In type theory for any $X: Type$ we have a 2-parametic type family $x,y: X \vdash x =_X y : Type$. An element of such type is a proof of equality between $x$ and $y$. It can be defined inductively as a universal 2-parametric type family generated by $x:X \vdash refl_x : x = x$. The details don't matter here, what matters is that for any $p,q: x=y$ you also have a type $p=q : Type$ et cetera. Thus it is obvious that to specify your algebraic structure you must also specify elements like $s: p=q$, where $p$ and $q$ are two different associativity morphisms $((a+b)+c)+d = a + (b+ (c+d))$.

A more-or-less universal example of such hierarchical object is a topological space (better, a simplicial set). That is, we interpret types as spaces, elements of types as points in spaces and equality types as the space of paths between two points. There are some technical issues, but the picture is like this. Formally such a structure is called $\infty$-groupoid. An $\infty$-groupoid is like a set but even better, since it carries information about the ways that we can identify its points. In particular, we can define many categorical notions with $\infty$-groupoids instead of sets, like $\infty$-categories (categories enriched over $\infty$-groupoids) and $\infty$-Lawvere theories. A particular case of $\infty$-Lawvere theories is the theory of (topological) operads and things like $E_n$-structures. There is actually quite a bit of technical issues to make it all work, but they can be overcome. A possible (but very intimidating) reference is the books "Higher topos theory" and "Higher algebra" by J. Lurie.

You can simplify the theory of $\infty$-groupoids by passing to n-truncation. A 0-truncation is just the category of sets: any two paths $p,q: x=y$ between $x,y: X$ are defined to be trivially equal. A 1-truncation is a 0-truncation on the level of paths, i.e. for any $x,y:X$ and $p,q:x=y$ we define that $p=q$ is just a set (all its paths are trivial). An n-truncation is defined inductively as (n-1)-truncation on the level of paths, but it quickly gets complicated. Note that 1-truncation of $Type$ is just the category of groupoids in the classical sense, i.e. categories such that any morphism is invertible. In this simple case you don't need the full-blown theory of $\infty$-groupoids and can specify all relations explicitly. For example, if you describe the 1-truncated theory of monoids, then you will come to the notion of a monoidal category. An analogue of abelian monoids is the notion of symmetric monoidal category, and there is also an intermediary ($E_2$) case of braided monoidal categories.

In summary, you need the notion of (probably multisorted) Lawvere theories enriched in groupoids. This structure remembers all the explicit relations that you want to specify. While you are more interested in the groupoidal structure, it makes sense to consider a Lawvere theory as a whole, since you should anyway explicitly define you n-ary operations that you are discussing.

Answer (score 3):

**What is this construction called, how can we rigorously define it, and where can I read about it?**

For starters, **it's a category and not usually a groupoid** because the morphisms need not be invertible and even for a theory with a single sort $X$ you need objects standing for $X^2$, $X^3$, ... in order to take account of binary, ternary, ... operations.

This category is known as a **Lawvere theory** and was introduced in his PhD thesis c1963. Such a category has **finite products**, although it is sometimes presented as its opposite, having coproducts instead.

The hom-sets $Law_T(X^n,X)$ of this category, ie the sets of *all* expressions in $n$ variables, had previously been known in Universal Algebra under the name of **clone**. I think this idea was due to Peter Hall.

The **universal property** of the Lawvere theory $Law_T$ is that models (algebras) for the theory $T$ in any category $C$ with finite products correspond naturally and bijectively to product-preserving functors $Law_T\to C$.

We can generalise from finite products to finite limits and the corresponding notion is called an **essentially algebraic theory**.  A leading example is that of categories.

However, such theories are often better described as **dependently typed**.  For example, a category *qua* essentially algebraic theory has a single type of *all* morphisms, with *conditional* composition, whereas it is more natural to take the *dependent* type $C(x,y)$ where $x$ and $y$ range over the type of objects.

Dependently typed theories with singletons and equality types are equivalent to essentially algebraic theories.  Without these, these is a class of distinguished **display maps** that needs to be closed under pullbacks. These were introduced in my PhD theses and described more (accurately and) fully in [Chapter VIII](http://paultaylor.eu/prafm/html/c8) of my book *Practical Foundations of Mathematics* (CUP, 1999).

A similar construction also lends itself to type-theoretic constructors such as quantifiers, as is described in Chapter IX of the book.   I describe the category as that of **contexts and substitutions**.

Comment: Peter Hall: should be Philip Hall, I believe.